# How can I use typcasting inside a JPQL statement?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, websphere-7

I have two `Integer` columns in the database (derby and db2). I need to divide them with each other inside a `JPQL`.

Both columns being of type `Integer` return zero if remainder is a decimal number e.g `0.25` becomes `0` etc and understandably so since type is int.

In `SQL` I could have this for example

`select CAST(column1 as decimal(6,2))/CAST(column2 as decimal(6,2))from Sometable;`

but what is `JPQL` equivalent .

One option might be (I have not tried yet) is to have a `@Transient` method in the entity returning the Decimal type and doing this calculation there and pass that to `JPQL` but I would rather let `SQL` do this work.

---

Mysql does not require casting at database level . So Behaviour for different RDBMS is different which is fine . But what should JPQL do with out needing to use a native query to know that cast to decimal is needed for this operation.

Adding dialect `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="derby"/>` did not fix it either.

*Please note it is JPA1*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have basically three options.

1. Use postload and let java do it .
2. Use a third Class and use New Operator in Select statement of JPQL
   to call constructor and inside that calls you can manage the
   datatypes which will be passed to SQL but you will get more then one
   kind of objects back which is fine just get the right one from right
   array index.More on this [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_constructor).
3. Third use Native Query like Idanmo said.

Answer (score 7):

That the division operator performs integer division on integer arguments is a feature.  In MySQL you have to explicitly choose `div` for integer division and `/` for floating point division, whereas in JPQL the choice is made automatically just like in Java.

So I suggest:

```
select (column1 * 1.0) / column2 from Sometable;
```

Comment: I found that in JPA (at least 2.0) the value returned when multiplication is used in the JPQL query winds up being a `BigDecimal`, which may not be what is expected (e.g. `Double`). However, I found a great solution for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786148/jpa-native-query-returns-double-or-bigdecimal

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there isn't a way to do this kind of cast in JPQL.

I suggest using JPA's native query execution which lets you run an SQL query like you would  if you were using JDBC.

For instance:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select CAST(column1 as decimal(6,2))/CAST(column2 as decimal(6,2)) from Sometable");

Double result = (Double) query.getSingleResult();
```

or

```
List<Double> results = (List<Double>) query.getResultList();
```

Comment: I would have expected div / operator to return a decimal without needing a cast but thats not happening .Also setting up the dialect would/should have taken care of this may be but not the case either. I am leaning towards nativeQuery as well but I am still not convinced that it is not only option . If it is then thats kind of sad really . +1.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you expect dialect to automatically do the casting?

Comment: @Kaushik because division of two integers produce a different datatype depending on underlying database. For example `Mysql` returns a decimal where as `Derby` and `DB2` integer which changes `0.25` to `0` for example . There fore dialect must know the behavior and provide a machinism especially given that option of a cast is not available in `JPQL'.