# JPA native query returns Double or BigDecimal

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, wildfly-9

I have the simple code below:

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "mycontext")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void getAggregatePower() {

    String sqlString = "SELECT SUM(power) FROM mytable";
    Object singleResult = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString).getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(singleResult.getClass().getName());

}
```

When I run this in a real environment, the print instructions prints `java.math.BigDecimal`. But when I run this in my unit tests environment, the print instructions prints `java.lang.Double`.
In both cases I use a WildFly 9 server and a Postgresql 9.4 database. I also use Arquillian for unit tests. For me, the only noticeable difference is the number of records in database.
The `power` column in `mytable` table is a `numeric(10,3)`.

I would like to avoid ugly code such as:

```
if (singleResult instance of Double) {
    ...
} else if (singleResult instance of BigDecimal) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to always have the same instance no matter my running environment ?

Comment: You can use double precision in place of numeric for more detail see :http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution since it's indicated this:
`If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary amounts), use the numeric type instead.`

Comment: why use a native query on something that JPQL would support (assuming "mytable" has an Entity) ...

Comment: @NeilStockton because in reality my request is much more complicated than the one in my exemple. There are subqueries for instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `BigDecimal` and `Double` extend `Number`, so you can do:

```
Number singleResult = ((Number) entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString).getSingleResult());
double resultAsDouble = singleResult.doubleValue();
BigDecimal resultAsBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(singleResult.toString());
```

Use `resultAsDouble` if you want the primitive type, but don't care about preserving the exact precision, use `resultAsBigDecimal` otherwise.

Comment: Maybe the best workaround. I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: This by far in my opinion is the safest solution.

Answer (score -1):

You may do this

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(power) FROM mytable";
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal)q.getSingleResult();
```