# QuerySyntaxException with hql

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2012, hql

I got an exception when I deploy the following query on tomcat :

```
@Query("select max(cast(substring(r.reference,9,4) as decimal(4,0))) from RequestDbo r  where substring(r.reference,0,9) = :referenceRoot")
Long getMaxReference(@Param("referenceRoot") String referenceRoot);
```

The exeption is :

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 54 [select
>   max(cast(substring(r.reference,9,4) as decimal(4,0))) from RequestDbo
>   r  where substring(r.reference,0,9) = :referenceRoot]

Althoug the query is ok when executed directly on sql server.

I see no syntax error in my hql...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Looks like your entire query is quoted by ORM with `[]`: `[select max(cast(substring(r.reference,9,4) as decimal(4,0))) from RequestDbo r where substring(r.reference,0,9) = :referenceRoot]`

Comment: The class contains other queries which are signed the same way and which are working well. example : @Query("select r from RequestDbo r")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not support this kind of casting `as decimal(4,0)` inside a JPQL query. You have four options as a workaround in here:

1. Load your data to Java and then get the highest value;
2. Use a Java class to cast the desired value and then call it's constructor inside the JPQL query;
3. Use native SQL;
4. Create a SQL function that cast the desired value and call this function inside the MAX of your query.

I also recommend you to take a look at this question [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544307/how-can-i-use-typcasting-inside-a-jpql-statement). Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Bonifacio. The issue was caused by the reason you mentionned. I finaly fixed it in removing the CAST and parsing on the java side instead of in JPQL.